# Swift + iOS: How to set notification.object to nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to set the window object to nil whenever a video in a web view tries to become full screen because I don't want it to take over the screen. I have this in my controller:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
        UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification,
        object: self.view.window,
        queue: nil
    ) { notification in
        notification.object = nil // <------ doesn't work because it's read only
        print("Video is now fullscreen")
    }
```

However, the `object` property is read-only. Would it be possible to set it to nil? Or would there be another way of intercepting the video that's about to be full screen and extract the video URL from that?

Thanks in advance.

== UPDATE ==

As suggested by Altimir, I've tried this: (Swift 2)

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
  UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification,
  object: self.view.window,
  queue: nil
) { notification in
  do {
    try notification.object?.remove()
  } catch {
    print("failed")
  }
  print("Video is now fullscreen")
}
```

However, this breaks my build.[image]

== UPDATE 2 ==

I tried this as well per Ozgur's suggestion:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(
  UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification,
  object: self.view.window,
  queue: nil
) { notification in
  do {
    try NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    print("success")
  } catch {
    print("failed")
  }
  print("Video is now fullscreen")
}
```

but the video still went to full screen when I clicked the youtube video in the webview.

Comment: That property is just the object that sent the notification.  Even if you could set `notification.object` to nil you would just be removing the reference from the notification object, not affecting the object in any way.  This notification just tells you that your key window is no longer the key window.  You can't use it to affect the new key window in any way

Comment: is there a way to prevent the fullscreen video from taking over? what if i did `let win = notification.object as! UIWindow` and then `win.hidden = true`?

Comment: No, because the notification is not the window.  When you receive this notification, the video has already "taken over" - this is the *did*resignKeyNotification - past tense.  Perhaps if you explained how the video is being triggered/presented someone could help, but the notification isn't going to help you.

Comment: the video would be presented in the web view as stated in the question. like when going to youtube and clicking on one of the videos, it plays it in fullscreen mode

Comment: Perhaps this  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28119739/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-ios-not-in-fullscreen ?

Comment: why do you want to set the notification to `nil` when you _observe_ a notification? the sender put the package together for you before _posting_ it, you can achieve __nothing__ if you could change the notification's details locally in your _observer_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (It's on Swift 3):

```
NotificationCenter.default().addObserver(
    forName: NSNotification.Name.UIWindowDidResignKey,
    object: view.window,
    queue: nil
) { notification in
    do {
        try notification.object?.remove()
    } catch {

    }
    print("Video is now fullscreen")
}
```

Comment: it didn't work, i updated my question with that code and the error that appears