# Play embedded YouTube video in iOS app, not full screen

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, uiwebview, youtube-api

I am trying to play YouTube videos in an app through the UIWebView. I realize that this is quite easy, but the video will automatically play fullscreen. Is there a way to play it not fullscreen, and furthermore, for the video size to change when the UIWebView's size is changed? I am looking for an answer in Swift.

I found a possible answer at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433036/3650087), but it was written in Objective- C and I found it quite difficult to translate.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, every time the UIWebView changes size, the iFrame player will reload.  You can't change that.

As for setting up, you're going to want to dynamically get the width and height of the device at runtime, and pass them into your UIWebView and player constructors.  This will play the video "inLine," but full screen.  Pass in whatever width and height values you want into the constructors to allow inLine playback without the video popping open to its full screen player.

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)

webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

let videoID = "zN-GGeNPQEg" // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN-GGeNPQEg

let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: hey, can i ask you question? 
how do you control the title of the webview - which is : public image Ltd -? 
in my app, when the youtube imbaded in full screen, the title of screen is so strange :S its : Playback_controls_view_controller !!! @_@ 
why?!

Comment: @Rawan you should ask a new question.

Comment: settings width & height didn't help in my case ... any other thoughts ?