# URL is not loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I have an URL with this format :

`https://www.youtube.com/e/Bif1Xw3mlfQ&list=PL0H-gXePWBUVL9hgxgOAyabXN7FKV-q5&index=2` , but i can't load it in web view .

this is how it looks in my code:

```
    NSString *part1=@"https://www.youtube.com/e/";
    NSString *webAddres=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@&list=PL0H-gXePWBUVL9hgxgOAyabXN7FKV-q5&index=2",part1,self.key];
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:webAddres];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

If i try to load https://www.google.com it's working

Comment: is it passing correct url to webview? Try debugging and check url passing to webview.

Comment: yes , the url is valid . i put it in a browser and it's ok

Comment: check self.key! may be the value of this is not as expected by you ! instead just as try to use **https://www.youtube.com/e/Bif1Xw3mlfQ&list=PL0H-gXePWBUVL9hgxgOAyabXN7FKV-q5&index=2** string as url directly please.

Comment: check if UIWebViewDelegate connection is set?

Comment: UIWebViewDelegate is set , and self.key has the right value

Comment: check my answer i have edited.

Comment: Remove list parameter. http://www.youtube.com/embed/Bif1Xw3mlfQ

Comment: Youtube not support "list" play in UIWebView. You can try opening your origin url in safari Youtube will redirect you to Youtube APP.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433036/3976183

Working Properly for most people.

Comment: another youtube url or any other URL?

Comment: with https://www.youtube.com/embed?e=Bif1Xw3mlfQ&list=PL0H-gXePWBUX-oM_kFKABayxWu5YWDqXx&index=2  for exemple

Comment: you want to play embedded video in UIWebView?  Right.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_HERE"]]];
```

For loading videos from URL have some classes try this

```
[Webview loadHTMLString:strVedio baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
[self embedYouTube:finalUrl frame:self.webView.frame];

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)urls frame:(CGRect)frame {

    CGFloat leftMargin = (self.view.frame.size.width - 300)/2;
    urls=[urls stringByAppendingString:@"?autoplay=1"];
    NSString *htmlString =[NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><head> <meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 300\"/></head> <body style=\"margin-top:%fpx;margin-left:%fpx\"><div><object width=\"212\" height=\"212\"><param name=\"movie\"value=\"%@\">",leftMargin,leftMargin,urls];

    NSString *htm2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</param><param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param><embed src=\"%@\"type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"212\" height=\"212\"></embed></object></div></body></html>",urls];

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",htmlString,htm2];
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

You have to embed the you tube url to play the video in webview
Hope this will solve your problem. Happy coding :)