# How do I make UIWebView pause/play video content programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I am making my app load a youtube video through a UIWebView but need to be able to have it pause and play at certain times.  I have looked at all the answers here and none of them are working.  I have tried this:

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("var videos = document.querySelectorAll(\"video\"); for (var i = videos.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { videos[i].pause(); };")
```

But that just does nothing.  If it matters, I am loading the video by this:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false    

let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='0' height='0' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL)
```

Comment: What iOS version are you using? Have you already taken a look at [this](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5204) thread? Alternatively, you could try the fix proposed in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19433036/4241842) answer (I assume similar logic follows if you want to use `pauseVideo()`).

Comment: The first link was perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [not_a_bot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4241842/not-a-bot) linked, using `ytplayer.pauseVideo()` and `ytplayer.playVideo()` works perfectly.

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("ytplayer.pauseVideo()")
```

or

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("ytplayer.playVideo()")
```