# Embedded YouTube videos in Html/WebView in NativeScript iOS

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to implement embedded YouTube videos in Html/WebView in Nativescript iOS. I was able to get it done on android, as I don't have enough native iOS experience I am posting the question here.
I found some links but they deal with native iOS in ObjC and Swift.

[How to embed YouTube video on iOs and play it directly on UIWebview without full screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15880101/how-to-embed-youtube-video-on-ios-and-play-it-directly-on-uiwebview-without-full)

Can someone guide me to get this done?

Update: Here is the screenshot of Android and iOS that I am getting by using  in src of WebView (Android) and html of HtmlView (iOS) -

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdlLC.png)

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLOm5.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that you could use NativScript WebView and bind its src property. For example:

main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">     
    <GridLayout>
        <WebView src="{{ htmlString }}" height="250" />
    </GridLayout>

</Page>
```

main-page.js

```
var observable = require("data/observable");

// Our new Observable view model for data binding
var viewmodel = new observable.Observable({});

// Page loaded      
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;

    viewmodel.set("htmlString", '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t1x8DMfbYN4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');

    page.bindingContext = viewmodel;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

You could also review [this article](https://bradmartin.net/2016/01/25/videos-in-a-nativescript-app/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using WebView in iOS over HtmlView does solve the problem.