# AllowFullScreen in webview nativescript (angular)

Tags: android, ios, angular, webview, nativescript

developing the webview I have run into the following problem:
I can not make a fullscreen of an element or video.

- https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.219824793.1845577720.1550136156-465475599.1539966593&template=play-ng&id=RDivWd&v=3

I have tried the following solutions:

- https://bradmartin.net/2016/01/25/videos-in-a-nativescript-app/
- [Embedded YouTube videos in Html/WebView in NativeScript iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773444/embedded-youtube-videos-in-html-webview-in-nativescript-ios?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the method I use to make any app go full screen. I don't know if it can help you.

```
private void fullScreen(){
    final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
            (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                    // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        // The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                        // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                        // other navigational controls.
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                    } else {
                        // The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                        // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                        // other navigational controls.
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer.
I would not know where to enter that code and if that would also work for ios.

How would I have to do it?
Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. You need to create a method/function like that then call it whenever you need to. For iOS, you'll need to look for a code that does the same thing. I don't have that much experience with iOS and haven't done some that needs to force fullscreen an app.