# Allow fullscreen to video player in webview Nativescript-vue

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm building an application on `Nativescript-vue` where I'm using webview to play HTML5 video player in it. I want this video player to go fullscreen but I'm to able to see any controls, I did some research and I came to know that it I need to give permission for fullscreen.

```
<WebView @loaded="onWebViewLoaded($event)" :src="url_to_be_fetched" />
```

In my webview I required local storage access also which I overcome by:

```
onWebViewLoaded(args) {
    console.log('check on load');
    const webView = args.object;
    if (webView.android) {
        webView.android.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.android.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    }
},
```

I came across the same issue but with angular [AllowFullScreen in webview nativescript (angular)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54705161/allowfullscreen-in-webview-nativescript-angular)

I'm  not sure how to implement in my vue app. I'm sure there must be some way out to it. Help me out, Thanks.

Comment: You will have to customize your WebView client, override [onShowCustomView(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient#onShowCustomView(android.view.View,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback)) callback in which you will add the incoming view to your root layout to make it fullscreen.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for heads up. Can you help me out with some sample code or any playground stuff, trying to find out so many links but not sure how it can fit-in into my project.