# YTSwiftyPlayer in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, youtubeplayer

I have used `YTSwiftyPlayer` in custom `UICollectionViewCell`.
When I am playing youtube video with video id in the cell it's playing as fullscreen.

```
var parameters = ["width": 
                  "100%",
                  "height": "100%",
                  "webkit-playsinline":1,
                  "playsinline":1,
                  "autoplay":1,
                  "modestbranding":1,
                  "rel":"0",
                  "controls":"1",
                  "fs":"0",
                  "allowfullscreen":"1",
                  "enablejsapi":"1",
                  "iv_load_policy":"3",
                  "showinfo":0] as [String : Any]

let youtubeID = "M7lc1UVf-VE"
cell.youtubePlayer.setPlayerParameters([.videoID(youtubeID),.showInfo(false),.showModestbranding(false),.showRelatedVideo(false),.playsInline(true),.autoplay(true)])
cell.youtubePlayer.loadPlayer()
cell.youtubePlayer.playVideo()
```

I want to play youtube video inside the cell, not as fullscreen

Comment: make  "allowfullscreen":"0" in your parameters and check

Comment: @MaheshDangar I will make change and check

Comment: @MaheshDangar after adding "allowfullscreen":"0" also not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433036/3359906 Check this answer, it shows how to play a YT video in a view and not in full screen, try it

Comment: Thanks to all for help.I have changed the [YTSwiftyPlayer] to [WKYTPlayerView].Now video is playing inline

Comment: is it possible to hide controllers on ios ?